# Create a ProcessObject for a process not made with StartProcess

Tags: customization, undocumented, external-calls

I am launching and linking to Mathematica from an external process and would like to be able to create a `ProcessObject` for the launching process that will support `ReadString` and `WriteLine` and things.

As things stand, my external process can communicate cleanly with Mathematica so that is not a difficulty that I'll need to overcome.

I figure I might be able to rewrite what `` ProcessLink`Private`startProcess `` does as it seems to not require very little info about / access to the actual process, but I was kind of hoping I could do things cleaner.

Is there a way to do this?